# Getting Facebook messenger messages from prior 2021

Tags: facebook

looking for some help, I am trying to download my information from Facebook, specifically the messenger messages. I have gone on to the settings and download your information and selected the date range as all time. When the file is downloaded in html as a zip i open the folder but the messages only appear to go back to 2021 (I have had my account since 2007) is there a reason that the messages dont go back any further? I have tried putting in custom dates before 2021 and nothing comes back. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way of recovering older messages than that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that messages prior to 2021 can be downloaded via the [Facebook "Download Your Information"](https://www.facebook.com/dyi) page. Messages in my download show timestamps dating back to 2007.

[image: Image showing date range starting prior to 2021]

I'd suspect that your messages prior to 2021 have been deleted or are not associated with your current account.